# How to define a class through annotations?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, annotations

I have several entities that need to be auditable, i.e. keep a change history. I can't use pre-built solutions, like Envers.

So I've defined the following abstract class.

```
public abstract class AuditoriaTable<T, S> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column()
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private S antigo;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private S novo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private T dono;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Lote lote;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime dataCriacao;

}
```

And this is an example implementation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "X")
public class AuditoriaExEntityField extends AuditoriaTable<ExEntity, Integer> {}
```

Even though I like this solution (btw, what are your thoughts?), I see myself repeatedly creating these really simple classes, and I thought it could be avoided through annotations, but I don't really know how. It would also be a good visual reminder that there's something else happening to that field.

Any good guidance?

Comment: I had to do this for a NO SQL DB. I would add an annotation column name that gets inserted into the DB. If the class has a name that is a pre-defined name (i.e "desc" for description, not descending), you can easily change the DB column to "notes" without changing the code. If you really want to get slick, you might also add a final superclass method to do the CRUD methods. If you keep it generic, it would handle all new classes without changing any DB code